# Which buildings in the LEGO Island video game were based on real-world sets?

Tags: set-identification, video-games

The [Wikipedia article for Lego Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Island#Setting) mentions  'Most of these buildings are based on real Lego sets in circulation at the time of release for the game.' I haven't played the game in a long time but the [6350 Pizzeria set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6350-1) reminds me of the Pizzeria in-game.

[image: Wikipedia image]

The jail cell looks like something out of a set whilst the bridge and beach hut don't.

Comment: Wow, I never realized that they released sets in conjunction with the game. Although I imagine it would make sense...

Comment: @RedriderX: I believe the game was based of sets already in production.

Comment: Oh, yes I see. I'll be interested to see the answer to this question too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While a few are indeed sets there are some I can't recall seeing (such as the Information Center, which was probably too specalised to deserve it's own set).

As already pointed out the Pizzeria set is very similar to the one in-game.

The set ["6598 Metro PD Station"](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6598-1) was the in-game police station, incuding jail. The helicopter could be build during in a minigame in the police station. Accessories like the box of donuts and flaming pizza were not included in the set.

[image][image]

The set ["6334 Wave Jump Racers"](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6334-1) was the beach lookout where you could start the jet-ski race around the island.

[image]

The Lego race cars in the game were similar to these sets: 1477, 1990, 1517 and 1612. I can't find the racetrack start itself but it was in keeping of the Octan branding that was used.

[image]

I thought the ambulance was set 6666 but I was wrong, the one in-game had a much longer sloped roof.
[image]

The Bank (which was always closed?) I can't really remember anything along the lines of, and I think the houses up on the hill were just generic lego houses.

Comment: The police helicopter did actually feature in the game when you visited the station, there was a minigame to build the helicopter.

Comment: @Ambo100, I only thought you had to build the JetSki, not the Helicopter...but then again it was a good 13+ years ago so forgive me if I can't remember exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [Race Track: Set 6337](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6337_Fast_Track_Finish)

[The Buggy: Set 6518](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6518_Baja_Buggy)

The [shuttle from Set 6339](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6339_Shuttle_Launch_Pad) is seen ingame (Race, Outro).

Also, the [fire engine from Set 6340](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6340_Hook_%26_Ladder) is in the game, possible that it looks a bit different.

On this site, people show their own LEGO Island Buildings, many of them are pretty good, like the Information Center: http://www.mocpages.com/group_mocs.php?id=8611

Comment: Many thanks for pulling those together and persevering with our "new user limits" - I've added those links into your answer for you :)

Comment: I think the Space Shuttle was only in Lego Island 2. Some of those fan made buildings for Lego Island are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the bank building was based on an alternative build of the 6598 metro pd station. It is not exactly the same, but it resembles the bank a lot. 
By the way, I'm currently working on the information center, but I'll have to order more pieces. My ultimate dream is to build a moc of the entire Lego island, but I'm afraid it'll cost me a lifetime.