# Which buildings in LEGO Island 2: The Brickster's Revenge were based on real-world sets?

Tags: set-identification, video-games

[Which buildings in the LEGO Island video game were based on real-world sets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/886/which-buildings-in-the-lego-island-video-game-were-based-on-real-world-sets) reminded me of LEGO Island 2, which I played when I was younger. I never played the original game so I don't know how many assets are reused.

Aside from the main island, the game also has several different areas. (Screenshots of every area of the game can be found at https://www.oocities.org/wonkeyzonkey/2/)

[image]

Castle Island:

[image]

Adventure Island:

[image]

[image]

Ogel Island:

[image]

I found [the buildings recreated by The Brickster on Rock Raiders United forum](https://www.rockraidersunited.com/gallery/album/468-lego-island-2-buildings/). No indication they came from any set.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the sequel to LEGO Island, many (but not all) of LI2's models are based on sets from 1998 to 2000.

Castle Island is based on LEGO Knights' Kingdom I. The castle itself, therefore, is loosely based on [6098 King Leo's Castle](https://brickset.com/sets/6098-1/King-Leo-s-Castle) (my 3rd most wanted set of all time).

[image: 6098 King Leo's Castle]

The battering ram shown in the screenshot is from [6096 Bull's Attack](https://brickset.com/sets/6096-1/Bull-s-Attack) (my 4th most wanted set of all time — yes, right after the castle).

[image: 6096 Bull's Attack]

Adventurers Island is based on the Dino Island and Desert subthemes of LEGO Adventurers. The Sphinx shown in the screenshot somewhat resembles the one in [5978 Sphinx Secret Surprise](https://brickset.com/sets/5978-1/Sphinx-Secret-Surprise).

[image: 5987 Sphinx Secret Surprise]

The Spaceport is from [6456 Mission Control](https://brickset.com/sets/6456-1/Mission-Control).

[image: 6456 Mission Control]

The Res-Q HQ is from [6479 Emergency Response Center](https://brickset.com/sets/6479-1/Emergency-Response-Center).

[image: 6479 Emergency Response Center]

[6332 Command Post Central](https://brickset.com/sets/6332-1/Command-Post-Central) is split into two parts: the main police station building, and the jail & helicopter/helipad.

[image: 6332 Command Post Central]

An exception is Nubby's gas station, which is a significantly modified version of [6397 Gas N' Wash Express](https://brickset.com/sets/6397-1/Gas-N-Wash-Express) from 1992 which was also rereleased in 2001 with the set number [6472](https://brickset.com/sets/6472-1/Gas-N-Wash-Express).

[image: 6397 Gas N' Wash Express]

The rest of the buildings appear to be unique to the game. Not even the new pizzeria seems to resemble any of the existing pizzeria sets.